# How to refresh a table that was fetched from database (FiveM Lua)

Tags: mysql, lua, fivem

I am trying to create a script that anyone can create a mafia at the spot with /createmafia command.

The thing is i am inserting the data to database but when i set the new mafiajob to the player it ignores it cause the es_extended script cant find the job at ESX.MafiaJobs table witch is fetched at every server restart.

Can i somehow force to fetch again the data from database before i do the setjob command?

Here is the function i am using:

```
function createmafia(mafia, identifier, grade)

    MySQL.Async.execute('INSERT INTO mafiajobs (name, identifier, label) VALUES (@name, @identifier, @label)',{
        ['@name'] = mafia,
        ['@identifier'] = identifier,
        ['@label'] = mafia
    }, function() end)
    
    MySQL.Async.execute('INSERT INTO mafiajob_grades (mafiajob_name, mafiagrade, name, label, identifier) VALUES (@mafiajob_name, @mafiagrade, @mafiagradename, @mafiagradelabel, @identifier)',{
        ['@mafiajob_name'] = mafia,
        ['@mafiagrade'] = grade,
        ['@mafiagradename'] = 'boss',
        ['@mafiagradelabel'] = 'Αφεντικό',
        ['@identifier'] = identifier
    }, function() end)

    MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE users SET mafiajob = @mafiajob, mafiajob_grade = @mafiajob_grade WHERE identifier =  @identifier ',{
        ['@identifier'] = identifier,
        ['@mafiajob_grade'] = grade,
        ['@mafiajob'] = mafia
    }, function() end)

    local xPlayer = GetPlayerFromIdentifier(identifier)
    xPlayer.setMafiaJob(mafia, grade)

end
```